# My class is not a servlet error

Tags: java, servlets

I have the following servlet code

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){

    Backup bup = new Backup();
    bup.doBackup();

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out;
    try {
        out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("You backed up your data - well hopefully");
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And the following stack trace

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Class
>   view.BackupServlet is not a Servlet
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   view.BackupServlet cannot be cast to
>   javax.servlet.Servlet
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

and the web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-<br>app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>Backup</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description>BackupServlet</description>
    <display-name>BackupServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>BackupServlet</servlet-name><br>
    <servlet-class>view.BackupServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BackupServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/BackupServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>`
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You haven't shown your class declaration - my guess is that your class doesn't extend `Servlet` or `HttpServlet`.

If it *does*, then check how many different servlet.jar files you have in your deployment - it could be that it's being loaded by two different classloaders.

Answer (score 5):

Your class containing the method `doPost` must extend `javax.servlet.Servlet`, but preferrably `javax.servlet.HttpServlet`

```
public class BackupServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) {
     .
     .
     .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely you have multiple versions of servlet libraries(.jar files) being loaded my the server. If you are using maven/gradle as build tool make sure you change the scope of the servlet library to scope if it is meant to be provided by the server.